# CruiseControl Request is too old

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

Yesterday my CruiseControl system started to log a "Request is too old" exception over and over into Windows' Event Log. This is the complete log:

```
    2012-02-19 17:47:02,921 [3] ERROR CruiseControl.NET [(null)] - Exception: Request is too old
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Request is too old
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseServer.ValidateRequest(ServerRequest request)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseServer.RunServerRequest(ServerRequest request, Nullable`1 permission, Nullable`1 eventType, Action`1 action)

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

I have over 17k error log entries with this type of error.
The machines that connect to CC have date and time updated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this exception when a user is using an older version of CCTray client to connect to the CruiseControl server. I would notify the user to get the latest CCTray client.